# WordPress Error establishing a MySQL database connection IIS10

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, iis-10, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to setup WordPress with MySQL on my local Windows 10 machine.
I'm getting this error:

> Error establishing a database connection
>   This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost:3307. This could mean your host's database server is down.

I already checked here: [Error establishing a database connection on wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302738/error-establishing-a-database-connection-on-wordpress)

1. Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
   Yes, I can login to SQL Server Workbench with the `root` credentials, so that is working
2. Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
   That's what I'm trying below
3. Are you sure that the database server is running?
   Yes, checked in MySQL workbench and it's running

I ran this query `select @@hostname` which gives me: `DESKTOP-CFT2ESY`

I tried adding to wp-config.php (not all at the same time):

`define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307');`
`define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8899');`
`define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`
`define('DB_HOST', 'DESKTOP-CFT2ESY');`
`define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');`

None of these work, it just changes the hostname string in the above error message.

I then added:
`define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

But that does not change the error message at all.

**UPDATE 1**

I ran `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` and my server runs on port 3306. In WorkBench I see my database is up and running.
I also added all privileges for user `root` on my database schema. My user's `Limit to hosts matching` is set to `localhost`.

**UPDATE 2**

I then ran this PHP code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583707/can-i-create-a-database-using-pdo-in-php/6549440#6549440) (I just changed the root user's password to my root user's password):

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 

$root="root"; 
$root_password="rootpass"; 

$user='newuser';
$pass='newpass';
$db="newdb"; 

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);

        $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db`;
                CREATE USER '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
                GRANT ALL ON `$db`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';
                FLUSH PRIVILEGES;") 
        or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

But this trows the error:

> DB ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

**UPDATE 3**

I then ran query: `SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S WHERE schema_name = "myDB";` which returns `utf8`, so the same character set as defined in my `wp-config.php`.

**UPDATE 4**
I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf). I just had a `mysqlrouter.conf.sample` in my `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\etc` folder, so I added a `my.cnf` file with:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

I restarted the MySQL windows service but the error remains the same.

What else can I try?

Comment: Your host does not seem to be the problem ... leave it to localhost. Make sure DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD is well defined. Maby a type in one of them?

Comment: You keep overwriting those, so only the last one takes effect.

Comment: Lol i am pretty sure he was just listing what he tryed

Comment: @PatrickSimard: I was indeed listing what I tried :-), I also rechecked name/user/password and literally copied them in workbench to test and it works there, so no typos. What else could it be? I'm running MySQL as a Windows service if that matters.

Comment: Have you checked if your DB is up and running, listens to the socket, and the user permissions permit the access from any host?

Comment: @EriksKlotins: I did, see update 1.

Comment: @Flo Remove the port in the `DB_HOST`. Its unnecessary. Aswell, try to create a simple PHP mysql connection via pdo or mysqli.

Comment: Set allowed hosts to % (everyone) and see if it makes a difference. Also, create a simple standalone php file to check and troubleshoot your db connection

Comment: @Xatenev: I'm currently already testing with just `localhost`. Do you have a sample PHP file you recommend for me? I don't work with MySQL a lot :-). @Eriks: I tried changing it to `%`, but it does not change the error.

Comment: @Flo https://stackoverflow.com/a/6549440/3223157 use the `new PDO(...)` line. Example: https://bpaste.net/show/4cecbad900d3

Comment: Have you tried: `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')`?

Comment: Have you tried creating a vanilla PHP project and connecting to the DB using PDO? Just to see if it's something WP end or if it's something between PHP + MySQL?

Comment: @treyBake: that's what I tried under update 2 right? If not: do you have an example I can use?

Comment: @Flo kinda - but you're trying to create a database through it, connect to a database and try select test data from a table

Comment: Tried `$dbh->exec("SELECT * FROM myDB.wp_terms;") 
        or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));`, but the error remains `Server sent charset unknown to the client.`

Comment: this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep ?

Comment: You can still change the default charset doing so `ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by @treyBake please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep).

Basically MySQL 8 changed the default charset to utfmb4 and there are now errors with some clients. I downgraded to MySQL Server 5.6 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Look here for the potential solution:

[PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep)

In essence, you have to make sure that both the DB and the script uses the same charset, preferably utf-8

UPDATE:
See also this:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: I suggest to leave wp alone and try to troubleshoot the problem with the standalone script. Have you checked you MySQL connection charset?

Comment: That is what I tried under update 3 right? It says utf8 already.

Comment: I am not sure how exactly the wp-config handles charsets. That is why I suggested working with the standalone script where you have full control. Importantly, the script charset, the connection charset, and the DB charset have to be the same for things to work.